# reading floating numbers from bin file continuosly and outputting in console window

Tags: c++, visual-studio-2010, fstream

I am making a code in visual c++ to read ( and see in console )the floating numbers from a bin file, The binary file contains around 2.5 million floating point numbers.

```
int main(){

   char* holder;

  ifstream fin;

  fin.open("male_16_down.bin",ios::binary|ios::in);

  if(!fin){

   cout<<" Error, Couldnt find the file"<<endl;

  }

  fin.seekg(0,ios::end);

  long int file_size_bin=fin.tellg();

  long int file_size=fin.tellg();

  fin.seekg(0,ios::beg);

  file_size=file_size/sizeof(float);

  holder=new char[file_size_bin];


  fin.read(holder,file_size*sizeof(float));

  float data=(float)atof(holder);

  cout<<data<<endl;



delete[] holder;
```

i know that 4 bytes for a float and 1 byte for char, this code outputs only one number that is 0,i believe `atof()` converts only the first byte to the number, but i want the whole number to be seen and  how can i see all the numbers in the binary file, 
any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: You're trying to convert whole 2.5 million chunk into a single floating point number ?

Comment: no, i want to see number by number... the whole contents of binary file in console window

Comment: then I don't see any loop, or some equivalent code

Comment: i can put a loop for each char,but i dont want to see char by char , i believe 4 char makes one floating point, how do i add up 4 char arrays, so that i can see the floating point  and put each of them in a loop,a see it in console window ?

Answer (score 7):

```
#include <fstream>
#include <iostream>

int main() {
    float f;
    std::ifstream fin("male_16_down.bin", std::ios::binary);
    while (fin.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&f), sizeof(float)))
        std::cout << f << '\n';
    return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 4):

Hopefully you plan to redirect the output to a file, or it's gonna take some time to print 2.5 million lines to a console, but ignoring that this is a way to do what you want.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <iomanip>
#include <fstream>
#include <vector>

int main()
{
    //Generate a file with some floats in it for testing
    std::ofstream fout("stuff.bin", std::ios::binary);
    float f;
    for(size_t i = 0; i < 100; ++i)
    {
        f = 3.14159f * i;
        fout.write(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&f), sizeof(f));
    }
    fout.close();

    std::ifstream fin("stuff.bin", std::ios::binary);
    if(!fin)
    {
        std::cout << " Error, Couldn't find the file" << "\n";
        return 0;
    }

    fin.seekg(0, std::ios::end);
    const size_t num_elements = fin.tellg() / sizeof(float);
    fin.seekg(0, std::ios::beg);

    std::vector<float> data(num_elements);
    fin.read(reinterpret_cast<char*>(&data[0]), num_elements*sizeof(float));
    for(size_t i = 0; i < data.size(); ++i)
    {
        std::cout << std::fixed << std::setprecision(3) << data[i] << "\n";
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: thanks ninja, i am new to this site, how do i accept the answer.